# PostgreSQL rule for using function on fields of certain type

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to fire a query in PostgreSQL like this:

```
SELECT id,foo,bar,geom1,geom2 FROM mytable
```

The fields "geom1" and "geom2" are of type "geometry".

But what I want for output is this:

```
SELECT id,foo,bar
      ,ST_asGeoJson(transform(geom1,4326))
      ,ST_asGeoJson(transform(geom2,4326))
FROM mytable
```

The name of the geometry fields can be anything. Also the queries can have more relations that one.

What is the best way of doing this? I was thinking of the rule system in PostgreSQL. The querying is done using PHP/PDO.

**Update**: I want to have the SQL rewritten in the database or in PHP. I'm building a SQL API and want to make it easier for the users.

Comment: What is the problem; the query looks fine to me. Do you have difficulties in PHP constructing and submitting the query, or getting the results back ?

Comment: I want to have the SQL rewritten in the database or in PHP. I'm building a SQL API and want to make it easier for the users.

Comment: If the problem is that the users should be able to specify which column(name) to use as a geometry column, you either put the column names in an (application) catalog/ application schema, or allow the users to specify them and use dynamic SQL. (A catalog is cleaner) First take a look at how others (postgis) solve the problem.

Comment: Just need to rewrite the query, so the geometry column(s) contains geojson instead of wkb. Users should be able to throw arbitrary select queries without worrying about ST_asGeoJson() and transform().

Comment: Why not make a view for every affected table? The clients could use the views instead of the table.

Comment: Yes, that would work and I can create the view on demand. But I realize that this will be limiting the users. If you do eg. buffer(geom1,1) using a view, you would actual be doing buffer(ST_asGeoJson(transform(geom1,4326),1), which will throw an error bacause ST_asGeoJson returns text. The right thing to do is ST_asGeoJson(buffer(transform(geom1,4326),1)).

Comment: The right thing to do is tell your users how to use these functions, or not expose an SQL querying facility to them at all. Every option in between is going to be a lot of work for very little reward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this:
My script creates a view from the submitted select query like this:

```
$view = "public.myview"
$createView = "CREATE VIEW {$view} as {$q}"; // $q="select *,buffer(the_geom,1) from public.mytable"

// $createView is fired.

// By using pg_meta_data on public.myview I can get a array with
// field names and types.
// When I loop through the fields of public.myview like this:

foreach($arrayWithFields as $key=>$arr) {
        if ($arr['type']=="geometry"){
            $fieldsArr[] = "ST_asGeoJson(transform(".$key.",4326)) as ".$key;
        }
        else {
            $fieldsArr[] = $key;
        }
    }
    $sql = implode(",",$fieldsArr);
    $sql = "SELECT {$sql} FROM {$view}";
```

In the end the view is dropped.

The output is this:

SELECT gid,id,ST_asGeoJson(transform(the_geom,4326)) as the_geom,ST_asGeoJson(transform(buffer,4326)) as buffer FROM public.myview

This method does not seem to be limiting the use of PostGIS functions or SQL